# How to create a column in CSS the same width as the larger writing?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

The text of the ‘same-width’ class must be the same width as the largest writing. If it is not possible to do it in css, please in pure javascript.

```css
.field {display: flex;}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Name</span>
          <input name="nome" placeholder="Energy">
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Drop down selection</span>
          <select required="" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">-- please select --</option>
              <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip help">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Checkbox</span>
          <span><input type="checkbox">
              I agree</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Check [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), specifically [`display: subgrid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid). Does that help you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a `<table>`

```css
td {padding: 5px 10px;}
img {width: 14px; position: relative; top: 1px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Blue_question_mark_icon.svg/200px-Blue_question_mark_icon.svg.png" title="name-tooltip-here">
    </td>
    <td><input name="nome" placeholder="Energy"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Drop down selection
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Blue_question_mark_icon.svg/200px-Blue_question_mark_icon.svg.png" title="dropdown-tooltip-here">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select required="" name="dropdown">
        <option value="">-- please select --</option>
        <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Checkbox
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Blue_question_mark_icon.svg/200px-Blue_question_mark_icon.svg.png" title="checkbox-tooltip-here">
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"> I agree</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Don't do this! The HTML spec specifically mentions that ["tables must not be used as layout aids"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element), and mentions "CSS grid layout, CSS flexible box layout ("flexbox"), CSS multi-column layout, CSS positioning, and the CSS table model" as alternatives. Further, WAI-ARIA describes `role=table` (`<table>`'s default) as ["a static tabular structure (that) is not an interactive widget"](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/table/). Not even `role=grid` applies here because the desired layout is purely visual.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a grid layout and put your labels in one column and the inputs in the other. There are lots of approaches to configuring grids. Below is just one approach. You can read about [different grid-related properties and using Grids on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids).

```css
.field {display: flex;}
label {display: contents;}
```

```html
<fieldset style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Name</span>
          <input name="nome" placeholder="Energy">
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Drop down selection</span>
          <select required="" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">-- please select --</option>
              <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip help">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Checkbox</span>
          <span><input type="checkbox">
              I agree</span>
      </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Using `display: contents` may cause some [accessibility problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#accessibility_concerns). Why not use [`display: subgrid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid)?

Comment: yeah. that's just me being lazy (busted!). this could really be done with the label not wrapping the input and being a sibling instead and using the `for` attribute.

Comment: If you are so keen on `display: subgrid`, @Oskar, then build us a snippet to demonstrate how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you *know*  the contents of the "largest writing" (i.e. the longest text), you can check its approximate width and apply that as `min-width` to a css rule for the `.same-width` class (plus you'll need to add `display: inline-block`, since `span`s are inline elements by default which would ignore width settings otherwise):

```css
.field {
  display: flex;
}

.same-width {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
    <label>
          <span class="same-width">Name</span>
          <input name="nome" placeholder="Energy">
      </label>
    <div class="tooltip">
      <span>?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>
          <span class="same-width">Drop down selection</span>
          <select required="" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">-- please select --</option>
              <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
      </label>
    <div class="tooltip help">
      <span>?</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label>
          <span class="same-width">Checkbox</span>
          <span><input type="checkbox">
              I agree</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Subgrids

You can try [subgrids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid)!

By making `.field` and `label` take up the columns they should inherit (see `grid-template-columns: subgrid`), we can place their children along the inherited tracks:

```css
fieldset {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
.field {
  grid-column: 1/-1; /*Take all columns from start to end*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}
.field>label {
  grid-column: 1/span 2; /*Take 2 columns beginning at start*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Name</span>
          <input name="nome" placeholder="Energy">
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Drop down selection</span>
          <select required="" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">-- please select --</option>
              <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip help">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Checkbox</span>
          <span><input type="checkbox">
              I agree</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Important note**: This will only work in [supporting browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid#browser_compatibility), e.g. Firefox or Safari. Currently, these do not include e.g. Chromium-based browsers like Chrome or Edge or Samsung Internet.

## JS solution

To match the elements' widths via JS, find the maximum width of all elements and apply that to all:

```js
const sameWidthElements = document.getElementsByClassName("same-width");

// Find maximum width among all widths
const widths = Array.from(sameWidthElements)
  .map(element => {
    return element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  });
const maxWidth = Math.max(...widths);

// Apply maximum width to all
for (const element of sameWidthElements) {
  element.style.width = `${maxWidth}px`;
};
```

```css
.same-width {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Name</span>
          <input name="nome" placeholder="Energy">
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Drop down selection</span>
          <select required="" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">-- please select --</option>
              <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip help">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Checkbox</span>
          <span><input type="checkbox">
              I agree</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Note**: [`width` does not apply to (non-replaced) inline box elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#preferred-size-properties), so we need to declare e.g. `display: inline-block` for `.same-width`. Also, you used `<div>` for your "tooltips", which makes them block-level elements, pushing them onto their own line.

By using a [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), you can reapply the correct width when the observed element resizes. This should ideally be the closest common ancestor, e.g. `fieldset`. Here is a naive example:

```js
const sameWidthElements = document.getElementsByClassName("same-width");
const fieldset = document.querySelector("fieldset");

const observer = new ResizeObserver(function onResize() {
  applySameWidthTo(sameWidthElements);
});
observer.observe(fieldset);

function applySameWidthTo(elements) {
  const widths = Array.from(elements)
    .map(element => {
      element.style.width = ""; // Don't forget to unset before measuring!
      return element.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    });
  const maxWidth = Math.max(...widths);

  for (const element of elements) {
    element.style.width = `${maxWidth}px`;
  };
  
  console.log(elements);
}
```

```css
.same-width {display:inline-block}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Name</span>
          <input name="nome" placeholder="Energy">
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Drop down selection</span>
          <select required="" name="dropdown">
              <option value="">-- please select --</option>
              <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <div class="tooltip help">
          <span>?</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
      <label>
          <span class="same-width">Checkbox</span>
          <span><input type="checkbox">
              I agree</span>
      </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

## Alternative: Change the HTML

An easier solution would be to: Change the HTML so that all elements that should be placed on the same grid are siblings.

By doing that, you can use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) *without* subgrids, which is generally [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid#browser_compatibility).

Since the controls will have to be moved outside their labels, you should associate them with the [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for) to maintain accessibility:

```css
fieldset {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="input-energy" class="same-width">Name</label>
  <input id="input-energy" name="nome" placeholder="Energy">
  <div class="tooltip">
    <span>?</span>
  </div>
  
  <label for="input-select" class="same-width">Drop down selection</label>
  <select id="input-select" required="" name="dropdown">
      <option value="">-- please select --</option>
      <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <div class="tooltip help">
    <span>?</span>
  </div>
  
  <label for="input-checkbox" class="same-width">Checkbox</label>
  <span><input id="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"> I agree</span>
</fieldset>
```

**Note**: Some `<span class="same-width">` elements have become obsolete due to moving the controls. In those cases I removed the `<span>` elements and applied their class to their parent `<label>` element.

Comment: So why would subgrids, which only work in some browsers, be a better solution than `display: contents;` which works everywhere, or `<table>` which works perfectly too? If you're especially concerned about accessibility, then sure change the HTML as you suggested, but for most people it's not a high priority.

Comment: @BrettDonald `display: contents` and `<table>` _don't_ work perfectly: Both come with accessibility issues or semantically incorrect code. Granted, subgrid is also not accessible to people using non-supporting browsers, hence my note and other solutions, which should be used as a fallback. If you are coding inaccessible websites despite knowing so, then you are knowingly making people's lives more difficult.